# How do I inject a bean in spring which is part of a class declared with @component tag

Tags: spring

My spring config is set to use auto scanning for beans.

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="mypackage" />
```

I have a class that is declared with `@Component`

```
@Component
class A{
   private InterfaceB b;
}
```

This `InterfaceB` is part of a jar file.

```
InterfaceBImpl implements InterfaceB{ 
// some contract here
}
```

I am getting an error from spring saying it cannot find a matching bean of type `InterfaceB`.

How can I inject that bean into the class?

Comment: Do you want InterfaceBImpl to be injected into class A? Does `@Autowired` exist on `private InterfaceB b`?

Comment: Yes I do want InterfaceBImpl to be injected into class A. I thought if I put a class level component then I don't need to use the field level autowired on InterfaceB b

Comment: `@Component` on `A` means that `A` is managed by Spring. And if `@Autowired` exists on any fields or methods, Spring will inject them. Could you please show the stacktrace because it is not easy to undertand what's going on

Answer (score 2):

1. `private InterfaceB b` in `A` has to be marked with `@Autowired`
2. But that doesn't enough, the `InterfaceBImpl` has to be a **bean**, too: or `@Component`, or as a `<bean>` in the xml config.

Comment: `InterfaceBImpl` also needs to be the only implementation of `InterfaceB` in the Spring context. If there's more than one, you'll need `@Qualifier([beanName])` alongside `@Autowired`. Also, it'd be a better design to use a setter around `private InterfaceB b` - putting `@Autowired` right above the private member variable hides the class's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a bean with the type **B** in your xml. Spring will automatically pick it up where you annotate a field with @Autowired.

Below is an example:

```
@Component
class A {

    @Autowired
    private B myB;

    //other code
}
```

And in your xml:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="mypackage" />

<bean id="myB" class="mypackage.InterfaceBImpl" />
```

Spring will see that **A** depends on **B**, looks in the context and sees that it has an implementation of **B**, which is **InterfaceBImpl** and inject it into **A**.

Comment: Will this be the same if I have an @inject on the constructor for class A?

Comment: Yes, if you have @Inject A(B b) it will works as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the sources of `InterfaceBImpl`, add a `@Component` annotation to make Spring creating a bean be available for auto wiring.

If `InterfaceBImpl` cannot be changed, you can 1) extend it and annotate the extension or 2) you can create a configuration creating the bean:

1)

```
@Component
class MyInterfaceBImpl extends InterfaceBImpl {
}
```

2)

```
@Configuration
class MyAdditinalBeans {
  @Bean
  public InterfaceB interfaceB() {
    return new InterfaceBImpl();
  }
}
```